# Публикация проекта на Vue 3.0 на VSL-сервере (TimeWeb)

Tags: vue.js, развертывание, vue-router, vue3, vue-cli

У меня есть проект на Vue 3.0, который я создавал через Vue CLI
Запустил сборку проекта с помощью `npm run build` и загрузил содержимое папки `dist` в файловый менеджер на хостинге

При переходе на сайт, где должен был бы лежать проект - отображается ошибка `Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server.`

Мой проект представляет из себя чистой воды фронтенд без какой либо бэкенда. Вычитал, что загрузки папки `dist` на сервер будет достаточно в моем случае.

Это код моего VueRouter'а

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/greetings',
      components: {
        theGreetingsPage: TheGreetingsPage
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/greetings/step1',
      components: {
        theStepOnePage: TheStepOnePage
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/greetings/step1/step2',
      components: {
        theStepTwoPage: TheStepTwoPage
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/greetings/step1/step2/step3',
      components: {
        theStepThreePage: TheStepThreePage
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/dataFromStore',
      components: {
        theStorageTest: TheStorageTest
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

А это мой vue.config.js

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  publicPath: '/'
})
```

Comment: Сама ошибка говорит, что запрошенного файла(url) нет на сервере. Проверяйте, куда вы что положили, по какому адресу обращаетесь и туда ли смотрит ваш хостинг для передачи файлов клиенту